# valgrind on mips

Tags: valgrind, coredump, mips32

I have been trying to run valgrind on a MIPS machine.
I successfully cross compiled valgrind and ran a few test from the test suite.
But whenever valgrind tries to create a coredump, an assertion fails. 
Its from the file coredump-elf.c

```
  vg_assert(sizeof(*regs) == sizeof(prs->pr_reg));
```

well apparently this assertion checks if the size of the byte array is same as the struct of registers made by the valgrind.

But i am not able to get past this error.

I am using valgrind on MIPS 32 machine.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Trunk Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/downloads/repository.html) is well supported for MIPS32 LE/BE and MIPS64 LE/BE.

Download the code from the trunk:

```
svn co svn://svn.valgrind.org/valgrind/trunk valgrind
```

configure it, make it, and use it. You should not see any MIPS32 issues.